Serilog and setting WriteTo configuraion
I am using serilog for my logging mechanism so in basics my Program cs looks like this;
IHostBuilder builder =
    new HostBuilder()
        .UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) =>
        {
            LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
            string? identification = context.Configuration["uuid"];
            if (!Guid.TryParse(identification, out Guid _))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Identifier '{identification}' is not a proper GUID value");
            }

            loggerConfiguration
                .WriteTo.Async(a => a.File(
                    path: $"Logs/log.{identification}-.log",
                    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Infinite,
                    fileSizeLimitBytes: 104857600,
                    retainedFileCountLimit: 5,
                    rollOnFileSizeLimit: true))
                .WriteTo.Console();

            Log.Logger = loggerConfiguration.CreateLogger();
        })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(app => app.SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory).AddCommandLine(args))
        .ConfigureServices((host, services) =>
        {
            services.AddScoped<ISomeService, SomeService>()
            // and some worker that uses that service
        });



await builder.RunConsoleAsync();

so now lets go to Some service
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using Serilog;

public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private readonly ILogger<ISomeService> _logger;

    public SomeService(ILogger<ISomeService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    // some methods
}

Now when i try to run it I am getting that DI can not resolve this ILogger<ISomeService> _logger, but when I change it to ILogger _logger it works. Why and how can I make it work with  ILogger<ISomeService> ?

Please add the "usings" from the top of your SomeService.cs - or, if you have those, global usings. My guess would be a name clash Serilog vs Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions

As I expected. 1. Remove using Serilog; 2. Add using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions; in the usings of SomeService.cs, then report back. Have the IDE add the Package Reference to the Abstractions Nuget if it prompts you to.

^^ The Issue is that both the Abstractions and Serilog have an ILogger. But those are not the same. Also, Serilog does not have an ILogger<T>. Now what can happen is you start off typing "ILogger logger" and your IDE will auto-add using Serilog;, when it should have added using Microsoft. ...; (Been there, done that, scratched my head ... )

^^ Don't worry, you will still be using Serilog - just through the Microsoft API, which is pretty commonplace, I've been told.
